# Не собираеться проект в Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle

Работал над проектом и словил не понятную ошибку.
Раньше собирался, теперь нет. Поиски и устранение неполадки привели меня к переустановке AndroidStudio и попытки собрать простой проект EmptyActivity.
Не собирается(((

Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.1.2', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

Думаю проблема может быть в этом

Есть идеи?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Установка VPN туннеля помогла. Установил windscribe.com